# MIN record within a group

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I want to get the record of MIN step per `user_id` based on `created_at` timestamp.

**The sample data:**

```
+---------+-------+---------------------+
| user_id | step  |     created_at      |
+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 7bc6de  | step1 | 2021-03-16 14:03:16 |
| 7bc6de  | step2 | 2021-03-16 14:04:07 |
| 7bc6de  | step2 | 2021-03-16 14:03:47 |
| 7bc6de  | step3 | 2021-03-16 14:03:55 |
| 7bc6de  | step3 | 2021-03-16 14:04:00 |
| 7bc6de  | step1 | 2021-03-16 14:04:02 |
| 7bc6de  | step2 | 2021-03-16 14:03:16 |
| 7bc6de  | step3 | 2021-03-16 14:04:07 |
| 7bc6de  | step4 | 2021-03-16 14:04:08 |
| 7bc6de  | step4 | 2021-03-16 14:04:09 |
+---------+-------+---------------------+
```

**The desired output:**

```
+---------+-------+---------------------+
| user_id | step  |     created_at      |
+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 7bc6de  | step1 | 2021-03-16 14:03:16 |
| 7bc6de  | step2 | 2021-03-16 14:03:16 |
| 7bc6de  | step3 | 2021-03-16 14:03:55 |
| 7bc6de  | step4 | 2021-03-16 14:04:08 |
+---------+-------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a case for the PostgreSQL extension `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id, step)
       user_id, step, created_at
FROM atable
ORDER BY user_id, step, created_at;
```